# Merge and save in json files nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

I'd like to add JSON object of a json file into another one.
Here is an example :

```
{
    "HOUSES": {
        "1": {
            "NAME": "House1",
            "PEOPLE": {},
            "ID": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "NAME": "House2",
            "PEOPLE": {},
            "ID": 2
        },
        "3": {
            "NAME": "House3",
            "PEOPLE": {},
            "ID": 3
        }
    }
}
```

And people object :

```
{

    "1": {
        "NAME": "People1"
    },
    "2": {
        "NAME": "People2"
    },
    "3": {
        "NAME": "People3"
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to add the people object into House1.

I tried that :

```
var extend = require('util')._extend;
var obj1 = house.PEOPLE; //var content : {}
var obj2 = extend(people, obj1); //var people content people object
```

This code replace all house1 by the people object. How can I add people object in the sublevel `PEOPLE` of house1?

I tried with object-assign too, and I have the same problem.

Thanks !

Comment: Please post a little more context to the code you posted and some output of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by:

```
HOUSES.1.PEOPLE = PEOPLEOOBJ;
```

Where PEOPLEOBJ is :

```
PEOPLEOBJ = {

    "1": {
        "NAME": "People1"
    },
    "2": {
        "NAME": "People2"
    },
    "3": {
        "NAME": "People3"
    }
}
```

Comment: This will suerly do.